# Dynamically added OLEObject. Events don't fire

Tags: excel, vba

I'm dynamically adding CheckBoxes to the Excel sheet using class module and want them to fire events.
So at first I add OLEObjects to the sheet and then I initialize them by creating my class objects with those OLEObjects and adding them to the Collection so that there was a single event handling function for all of the CheckBoxes.

If I run the subs to add OLEObjects and then to initialize them separately then it works OK. Events are fired. But if I combine adding OLEObjects and initializing then no events are fired. More so if the OLEObjects were previously initialized and events were OK and then I add another OLEObject then it seems like it disables events from all the OLEObjects. Application.EnableEvents = TRUE all the time

Here is the code.
Class module (clsCheckBox):

```
Public WithEvents cmdCheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub cmdCheckBox_Change()
    MsgBox "Changed"
End Sub
```

Code in the sheet module:

```
Dim coll_obj As Collection

Public Sub InitializeObjects()
    Dim myObj As OLEObject
    Dim obj As clsCheckBox

    Set coll_obj = New Collection
        For Each myObj In Worksheets("Objects").OLEObjects
            If TypeName(myObj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
                Set obj = New clsCheckBox
                Set obj.cmdCheckBox = myObj.Object
                coll_obj.add obj
            End If
        Next myObj
    Set obj = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub AddObjects()
    ' a set of something like this
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.add "Forms.CheckBox.1", Left:=10, top:=10, Height:=13, Width:=13
End Sub
```

So if I first run AddObjects and then InitializeObjects then CheckBoxes events are fired. But if I run the following events don't fire

```
Public Sub DoObjects()
    AddObjects
    InitializeObjects
End Sub
```

Also if the OLEObjects were previously initialized and events were fired OK and then I add another OLEObject like again run AddObjects then events stop firing even if the objects exist in the collection and Application.EnableEvents = true

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the event inside your class. Try modifying your class in the next way:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cmdCheckBox  As MSForms.CheckBox


Public Sub Initialize(ByVal ctrl As MSForms.CheckBox)
    Set cmdCheckBox = ctrl
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCheckBox_Change()
    MsgBox "Changed"
End Sub
```

At least, this is the wrapper class I used when created controls on the fly. I did not try reproducing your code and testing it.

And  this piece of code is not my creation. I found something similar on the net some years ago and I adopted it...

Comment: Thank you but still doesn't work. I found that when the Objects are initialized and events are firing OK and if I switch to design mode and then back events doesn't fire anymore. Even if the objects are still in the Collection. Probably it's somehow related. Probably OLEObjects can only be added in design mode and adding the OLEObject dynamically still means going to the design mode each time to add the OLEObject and then back.

Answer (score 0):

I found it's a known issue with ActiveX objects. The solution is splitting the process and use each part on a separate event. Like I can use button to run the process and add objects on button_MouseDown event and initialize objects on button_Click. That works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use application.ontime:
(in this case your IntitalizeObjects will run *after* the End sub of DoObjects()

```
Public Sub DoObjects()
    AddObjects
    Application.OnTime Now, "InitializeObjects"
End Sub
```